# Dynamically choose controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm writing routing for an app that will have a lot of similar routes, and I want to keep things DRY, so I want to choose the controller based on a segment of the URL, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with Laravel.

This doesn't work, because the `$report_slug` is not available.

```
Route::get('/ad-reports/{report_slug}', array('uses' => Str::title($report_slug).'Controller@showHome'));
```

If I use a closure I have access to `$report_slug`, but I can't find any documentation for what to replace `return` with, so this returns the text of the controller and action, but obviously I want to use that action.

```
Route::get('/ad-reports/{report_slug}', function($report_slug) {
   return (Str::title($report_slug).'Controller@showHome');
});
```

How can I specify the controller based on the `report_slug`?

Comment: Just found a way of doing it easily `Route::get('ad-reports/{report_slug}', Str::title(Request::segment(2)).'Controller@run');`. Edited my answer to provide this as first way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call App::make in route like below. It'll work as you want

```
Route::get('/ad-reports/{report_slug}', function($report_slug) {
return App::make($report_slug.'Controller')->showHome();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Option 1

To use it dinamically you can do:

```
Route::get('ad-reports/{report_slug}', Str::title(Request::segment(2)).'Controller@run');
```

Worked for me, this is the controller I used to test this route:

```
class FooController extends Controller {

    public function run()
    {
        return "this is a dynamic controller call";
    }

}
```

#### Option 2

You can create a proxy controller to find your controllers based on your route parameters:

```
class ProxyController extends Controller {

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $class = Str::title($arguments[0]).'ReportController';

        array_shift($arguments);

        $controller = new $class;

        return call_user_func_array(array($controller, $name), $arguments);
    }

}
```

This is the route:

```
Route::any('ad-reports/{report_slug}', 'ProxyController@bar');
```

This is a controller example:

```
class FooReportController extends Controller {

   public function bar()
   {
       return 'generated by foo report!';
   }
}
```

And you just have to hit

```
http://yourdomain.com/ad-reports/foo
```

To see:

```
generated by foo report!
```

Comment: It's an alternative to not create the ProxyController. I just added a controller I used to test here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.... I'll delete my comment since it no longer adds value to later users...

Comment: This was an excellent answer, so I feel like I owe you an explanation for why I chose Muharrem's answer.  Although his is a bit more verbose, it's also a bit clearer, and probably easier if you refactor your routing, owing to the fact that `$report_slug` is available inside the closure but cannot be available inside the second argument of `Route::get()`  Nonetheless *thank you* for the help: I really appreciate it.